# What's analog MSG_WAITALL in QLocalSocket

Tags: qt, sockets, posix

How to set analog of posix flag MSG_WAITALL for QLocalSocket?
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html

> MSG_WAITALL (since Linux 2.2)
>                 This flag requests that the operation block until the full
>                 request is satisfied.  However, the call may still return less
>                 data than requested if a signal is caught, an error or
>                 disconnect occurs, or the next data to be received is of a
>                 different type than that returned.  This flag has no effect
>                 for datagram sockets.

Comment: Closest is `waitForReadyRead()`

Comment: "waitForReadyRead  - Blocks until new data is available". It does not look like "block until the full request is satisfied". What do you think?

Comment: Yes it's not exactly what you ask for (you might have to loop until you get the data you want), but I think that's the closest available from QLocalSocket.

Comment: The `MSG_WAITALL` is not a panacea since one still has to check whether the whole buffer was received or some error has occurred or syscall has to be restarted. Thus the loop around receive is not unavoidable.